# Buscar imagem bmp no banco e mostrar na view.

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, laravel

Tenho uma imagem bmp salva no banco de dados, porém esse arquivo já está no banco e não foi incluso no pelo framework, gostaria apenas de saber como faço pra mostrar essa imagem na view.

Obs: Já tentei o método:

No Controller:

Pego os registros desejados e acesso o campo que contém a imagem.

```
$query->resultado;
```

Na View:

```
<img src="{{asset('data:image/bmp;base64,'.base64_encode($query->resultado).'')}}">
```

Tentei outras formas indicadas na internet e não tive sucesso, se alguém puder me dar alguma luz que seja já me ajudaria muito.

Comment: Qual o framework que você está usando?

Comment: Estou usando Laravel, marquei na tag em baixo !

Comment: qual é o resultado que você está tendo na variavel $query->resultado? coloque esse resultado para ficar melhor o entendimento!

Comment: Como o campo contem uma imagem, o retorno é. -----> 789C73F2FDC6C600066640AC01C41250CC082619180E00E58FF041302DC17F30C0148108E2626335044D16AE0B4E228BE3720CA6AB4835074D2F31E6E0F2142EB711EF1E5CC14B5D73488DAFA102F0443125E6901126FF51019A2019A66172A962CE5089F1FF18800123F5222B66C0C88068B2B844883707BFC958F32C9E0047D38B6629D6BC4F30B513740F2EABF1A45B3CB140F5840400DE63AA05

Comment: @LincolnBinda, o base64 desse retorno ñ parece uma imagem: Nzg5QzczRjJGREM2QzYwMDA2NjY0MEFDMDFDNDEyNTBDQzA4MjYxOTE4MEUwMEU1OEZGMDQxMzAy
REMx4oCM4oCLN0YzMEMwMTQ4MTA4RTI2MjYzMzXigIzigIswNDREMTZBRTBCNEUyMjhCRTM3MuKA
jOKAizBDQTZBQjQ4MzUwNzREMkYzMUU24oCM4oCLRTBGMjE0MkVCNzExRUYxRTVDQzHigIzigIs0
QjVENzM0ODhEQUZBMTAyRjA0NOKAjOKAizMxMjVFNjkwMTEyNkZGNTEwMTlB4oCM4oCLMjAxOUE2
NjE3MkE5NjJDRTUwODnigIzigItGMUZGMTg4MDAxMjNGNTIyMkI2NuKAjOKAi0MwQzg4MDY4QjJC
ODQ0ODgzNzA34oCM4oCLQkZDOTU4RjMyQzlFMDA0N0QzOELigIzigIs2NjI5RDZCQzRGMzBCNTEz
NzQwRuKAjOKAizJFQUJGMUE0NUIzQ0IxNDBGNTg04oCM4oCLMDQwMERFNjNBQTA1IOKAkwo=

Comment: @LincolnBinda para ver se funciona, sugiro pegar o retorno do base64_encode($query->resultado) e substituir em uma tag `<img>`estática: <img src="data:image/png;base64,[imagem codificada em base64]" />

Comment: @nunks.lol muito obrigado por se dispor a ajudar, porém é exatamente isso que eu fiz, quando eu coloco o retorno do resultado da query em base64 em uma tag <img> ele simplesmente não aparece, como se não existisse a imagem, porém existe pois eu a coloquei em tempo real.

Comment: @LincolnBinda entendo, é o que aconteceu aqui comigo tambem usando a base64 do retorno que vc postou num comentario acima. O que quero dizer é que isso nao parece uma imagem, mto menos um BMP, porque é muito pouca informação. Peguei [essa imagem](http://hwzhiyin.com/uploadfile/snowfall/Samsung/Digimax%20Master/Edges/Vignette/Circle.bmp) de um circulo preto, reduzi para 10x10 px e mesmo assim o base64 retornado é maior do que cabe em um comentário do stackoverflow. Você tem uma forma de garantir que o encode da imagem está correto na hora de inserir no banco?

Comment: @nunks.lol entendo, não tenho nenhuma forma de garantir sobre o encode na hora de inserir no banco, até porque a imagem é inserida através de um jogo, funciona assim, o personagem cria uma guild, essa guild possui a opção de ter emblema, quando muda o emblema da guild, automaticamente o registro da guild da tabela do banco de dados ganha o emblema em um de seus campos, que no caso se chama 'emblem_data'.

Comment: experimenta salvar um emblema em disco manualmente e executa `base64 [nome_do_arquivo]` (isso funciona no linux) pra comparar o resultado com o mesmo emblema consultado no banco, talvez dê uma luz... qual o seu codigo pra inserir a imagem no banco?

Comment: Verifique o tamanho do campo em sua tabela, o resultado pode está sendo salvo faltando informação por conta do espaço reservado para este campo!